# Bash: changing file extentions of all files in a directory and copying odd lines

Tags: bash

How would one go about taking all the `*.txt` files in a given folder (users input) and copying odd lines to files with identical names but different extension (bat/html or anything else)

I assume `cp` or `mv` wont work, something like `sed` should do the trick for lines, but im having a hard time incorporating everything together.

If anyone could help me piece this together I would be very thankful

```
#!/bin/bash
clear

#seems like a good idea to get a full path to the directory im gonna be working in, not #sure how to go about it though. 

path=pwd

#getting users input

read Directory

#check if said directory exists
if[ -d $Directory]; then
#if it does
#all files with .txt extention are to be copied 
for *.txt in $(ls)
do
mv *.txt *.bat

#aaand now im lost, didnt have a chance to even test this, since i have linux only in #my studying enviroment (uni), will get on my personal PC later on
#something like sed could/should work in there, but i have no idea how to go about it

#if doesnt
else
echo "Directory does not exist or you do not have a permission to alter its contents"
```

Comment: Do you want to move the odd lines into one file or into different files?

Comment: I want to copy odd lines into different files.
For example
1.txt -copy odd lines to-> 1.bat

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#!/bin/sh 
cd "$1" || { echo "Couldn't cd to directory $1.  Quitting." ; exit 1 ; } 
for fname in *.txt
do
    awk 'NR % 2 == 1 { print; }' "$fname" >"${fname%.txt}.bat"
done
```

Put the above in a file and make the file executable (`chmod +x yourfilename`).  Now, run this command with the directory that you want to operate on as the first argument.

The script changes to the directory you request (`cd "$1"`).  If that fails (the directory doesn't exist), then the script exits with an error message.  If `cd "$1"` succeeds, then the script goes through each `.txt` file in the directory, selects the odd lines (`NR % 2 == 1`) and writes them to a file with same name except with extension ".bat".

Comment: Thanks! Seems so simplistic now that i look at it

Have to look up awk, since im unfamiliar with this command

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by "odd lines"[1], but this statement achieves just what your code currently attempts to do:

```
cd "$1" && rename 's/\.txt$/.bat/' *.txt
```

No need to do your own error messages, the shell will do them just fine.

[1] This makes it sounds a lot like a Uni homework assignment.

Comment: odd lines from the .txt files im renaming.
Pretty much is, had C all semester that i was acquainted with prior to uni, so completed all C assignments, got a scripting one to get familiarized with Unix. Lots of things to learn, and after C/C++ and some Assembly, doing things globally by type, instead of looping through all elements one-by-one is a new concept that i need to get used to.
Cheers!

Answer (score -1):

Thank you to all that have replied, you have helped me greatly in gaining some understanding of bash scripting, now that this question is resolved, how would one go about closing a question?

I used script provided by John1024, worked flawlessly. Very thanful for that. Cheers

## !/bin/sh

cd "$1" || { echo "Couldn't cd to directory $1.  Quitting." ; exit 1 ; } 
for fname in *.txt
do
    awk 'NR % 2 == 1 { print; }' "$fname" >"${fname%.txt}.bat"
done

Comment: If the answer given by @John1024 worked for you then please accept it rather than adding your thanks as an "answer" - see http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer